# raise dont reraises ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, raise

I am trying to handle particular ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid exception and fall back to default on different exception

```
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => error
  handle_specific_record_invalid_errors(error)
```

private method

```
  def handle_specific_record_invalid_errors(error)
    if error.record.errors.added?(:number, :taken)
      fail  MyCustonErrorClass
    else
      raise # This must re-raise the last exception, but fails rspec text, if I do (raise error) it works.
    end
  end
```

and in rspec test

```
let(:record) { build(:record) }
#this test works
it 'should raise Parsing::Errors::InvoiceAlreadySavedError' do
  record.errors.add(:number, :taken)

  exception = ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new(record)
  expect do      StoreParsedInvoice.new(some_data).send(:handle_specific_record_invalid_errors, exception)
end.to raise_error(MyCustomErrorClas)
end

#and this test fails with DRb::DRbConnError: druby://127.0.0.1:8989
it 'should raise ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid' do
  record.errors.add(:number, :blank)

  exception = ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid.new(record)
  expect do
  MyClass.new(some_data).send(:handle_specific_record_invalid_errors, exception)
  end.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
end
```

error output

```
 Failure/Error: expect do
   expected ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, got #<DRb::DRbConnError: druby://127.0.0.1:8989 - #<Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 8989>> with backtrace:
     # /home/agm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/drb/drb.rb:744:in `rescue in block in open'
     # /home/agm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/drb/drb.rb:738:in `block in open'
     # /home/agm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/drb/drb.rb:737:in `each'
 # /home/agm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/drb/drb.rb:737:in `open'
 # /home/agm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/drb/drb.rb:1248:in `initialize'
 # /home/agm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/drb/drb.rb:1228:in `new'
 # /home/agm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/drb/drb.rb:1228:in `open'
 # /home/agm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/drb/drb.rb:1141:in `block in method_missing'
 # /home/agm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/drb/drb.rb:1160:in `with_friend'
 # /home/agm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/drb/drb.rb:1140:in `method_missing'
```

Comment: Why not do what is in your comment? In your `handle_specific_record_invalid_errors(error)` method, just do `raise(error)` in the `else` clause.

Answer (score 0):

When you write this:

```
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => error
  handle_specific_record_invalid_errors(error)
end
```

It actually will only rescue exception `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` and call `handle_specific_record_invalid_errors`, and any other exceptions will still be risen and it WON'T go to `handle_specific_record_invalid_errors`.

Comment: I need to handle one specific error :number, :taken

Comment: still can't understand your intent? could you please explain it more clearly